# The preimage of convergent bounded linear functional images

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

I have a question that could be trivial:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, with a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset X$. If
> $\forall f \in X^*, f(x_n) \to 0$, is it true that $x_n \to 0$ in $X$?

My idea is to first prove that $x_n$ should be convergent, and then use contradiction to prove that $x_n \to 0$. But I don't know what should be the whole picture of the proof. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Weak convergence does not imply strong convergence

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way this is true. A trivial counter example can be obtained from any infinite dimensional Hilbert space:

Let $H$ be a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Take an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ for $H$. By Riesz's representation theorem, any $f\in H^*$ is of the form $\langle\cdot,x\rangle$ for some $x\in H$. Now since
$$x=\sum_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$$
we have that $\langle e_n,x\rangle=\overline{\langle x,e_n\rangle}\to0$ and this is true for all $x\in H$, thus $f(e_n)\to0$ for all $f\in H^*$. But it is obvious that $e_n\not\to0$: Since $e_n$ is orthonormal, $\|e_n\|=1$ for all $n$ and thus $\|e_n\|$ does not get arbitrarily small (i.e. $e_n$ does not converge to zero).